# Getting a value from an MVC 3 Razor RadioButton list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

I'm coming from a WebForms environment. When I wanted values from a radiobutton, the form simply got ajax reposted or I got it thru javascript.

I've searched the web, but can't seem to find an equivalent for **MVC 3 Razor**.

I'm not posting the form, so I **can't** use the FormCollection object in the ActionResult.

I simply want to get the value of which option in the RadioButton is checked when a user checks one of them.

I assume I would do this thru an Action method in a Controller once a user checks one of the values.

Note also, that this radiobutton list is in a partial view and is available to the entire website (because it is in my _Layout.cshtml view).

Can someone please help me out with what I think should be a simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981152/asp-net-mvc-html-radiobutton-onclick-set-viewdata/981202#981202). MVC does not have the concept of an Auto-Postback like in Webforms. This is an optimization in the page loading time (no self-managed viewstate). This means you need to manage the statefulness of controls yourself.

Comment: This sounds lame, but I checked out those answers and doesn't seem to give me a simple answer. If I could just get a simple code example, that should suffice.

Comment: What's the purpose of knowing the radio button's value? Is it to change the content on the page, to redirect, etc? The intentions determine which route you should take.

Comment: It's to set the language culture. I want to be able to run an Action method in the controller based on the selected language to set the culture when a user changes it.

Comment: If I need to use jQuery I can use the below syntax. $('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val() However, I'm not using a FORM. In addition, what kind of variable can I use to get the value out of the jQuery statement. After getting that value, I need to be able to set the language culture. This needs to happen when a user changes the language.

Comment: @sagesky36 - you need to post a new question with new tags. Your original question is now deviating off-topic. Please accept the answer above and resubmit your new question to get guidance on your next steps.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if you're not posting (or "getting") the form then the value won't be available in the controller...more specifically, neither the controller nor it's actions will be called at all.

If you're trying to do something strictly UI related, then you may want to consider [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

If you're trying to do some sort of model validation inside of the view, you may want to reconsider your approach and usage of the MVC pattern.

Comment: It's to set the language culture. I want to be able to run an Action method in the controller based on the selected language to set the culture when a user changes it.

Comment: Note that this is done without a named FORM. It's just either on a view with text or on a view with a model.

Comment: If I need to use jQuery I can use the below syntax. $('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val() However, I'm not using a FORM. In addition, what kind of variable can I use to get the value out of the jQuery statement. After getting that value, I need to be able to set the language culture. This needs to happen when a user changes the language.

Comment: I think I can see where you're going with this.  If it were me, for an MVC application I would do it with a FORM.  Possibly using JavaScript to submit onClick for the RadioButton(s), but nothing more.  You've already told us that you want to run an Action when this value changes, so submitting a form makes perfect sense. And rather than RadioButtons, I would probably use a drop down box, based on the potential number of (future) options and the fact that they are on the _Layout page always taking up real estate...putting them in a drop down will help save space.